# Heuristic argument for boson of Möbius graphene strip at low temperatures?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, phase-transition, graphene

I recently was thinking of the implications of how electrons behave in the Möbius graphene strip at **low** temperatures.

At **high** temperatures we know that there will be a parity symmetry of the system which the Hamiltonian will respect. However, I think at **low** temperatures this symmetry will be broken. Why? Because the vacuum fluctuations will become important and they will not respect the parity of the system. From Goldstones theorem we know when ever a continuous symmetry is broken, there will appear a mass-less boson.

### Questions

Have people already thought about the contribution of vaccum fluctuations? Is the above argument correct? Heuristically, what is a **low** and **high** temperature estimate? What is the new boson which will appear? Usually, one heats the system to break a symmetry but now one will cool it! Since, there is a new boson at low temperatures I'm expecting a discontinuity in the heat capacity of the system as:

$$C_V = \frac{\partial U_{0} + U_{\text{new boson}}}{ \partial T}$$

Where $C_V$ is the heat capacity and $U_0$ is the original system's without taking into account of the vacuum fluctuations and $U_{\text{new boson}}$ is the potential energy of the new boson. Where is the system getting energy for this new boson (as the experimental physicist will be cooling the system down)?